# Position absolute div hides after going outside of its parent container and into another container

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, react-bootstrap

The title almost says it all. But here I provided some examples and a sandbox for you to see what I'm talking about.
Here is a [link to the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-hooks-qrk6u?file=/src/App.js:0-3396) that I created and added all dependencies.
As you can see in the first picture, my dropdown menu goes behind everything and part of it literally becomes hidden. It's there but not visible

[image: partially hidden dropdown]

And here is what a dropdown should look like:

[image: Complete dropdown]

I thought to myself that the problem might be because of the `z-index`. But the element has a `z-index: 1000;` style applied to it and you can see the applied styles and selected element in chrome inspect in the below picture. As you can see the element's full rectangle is highlighted in inspect but is not visible.

[image: inspected dropdown]

But there is a `position: fixed;` header with a dropdown menu inside of it which uses react-bootstrap dropdown as well. But it is shown perfectly and without any problems. I gave that header a static position and here is the result. The dropdown was still being shown perfectly.

[image]

I've been thinking and searching about this problem for weeks and still couldn't find a solution. Any help will be much appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
import React from "react";
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import DataTableExtensions from "react-data-table-component-extensions";
import "react-data-table-component-extensions/dist/index.css";
import { Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";

function UsersAdmin() {
  const users = [
    {
      id: 1,
      first_name: "test",
      last_name: "test",
      email: "test",
      mobile: "test",
      avatar: "avatar.png",
      created_at: "2021-11-15T19:14:44.000000Z",
      updated_at: "2021-11-15T19:14:44.000000Z"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      first_name: "test",
      last_name: "test",
      email: "test",
      mobile: "test",
      avatar: "avatar.png",
      created_at: "2021-11-15T19:14:44.000000Z",
      updated_at: "2021-11-15T19:14:44.000000Z"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      first_name: "test",
      last_name: "test",
      email: "test",
      mobile: "test",
      avatar: "avatar.png",
      created_at: "2021-11-15T19:14:44.000000Z",
      updated_at: "2021-11-15T19:14:44.000000Z"
    }
  ];

  const columns = [
    {
      name: "language item",
      selector: "id",
      sortable: true,
      width: "90px"
    },
    {
      name: "language item",
      selector: "first_name",
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      name: "language item",
      selector: "last_name",
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      name: "language item",
      selector: "email",
      sortable: true,
      grow: 1.5
    },
    {
      name: "language item",
      selector: "mobile",
      sortable: true
    },
    {
      name: "language item",
      selector: "created_at",
      sortable: true,
      grow: 2
    },
    {
      name: "language item",
      cell: (row) => (
        <div style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}>
          <img
            src={`${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/storage/${row.avatar}`}
            style={{ width: "100%", borderRadius: "50%" }}
          />
        </div>
      ),
      width: "75px"
    },
    {
      name: "language item",
      cell: (row) => (
        <Dropdown>
          <Dropdown.Toggle size="sm" />
          <Dropdown.Menu size="sm">
            <Dropdown.Item>
              <i className="fa fa-edit mr-1" /> {"language item"}
            </Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item>
              <i className="fa fa-download mr-1" /> {"language item"}
            </Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item>
              <i className="fa fa-download mr-1" /> {"language item"}
            </Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item>
              <i className="mdi mdi-eye mr-1" /> {"language item"}
            </Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
      ),
      width: "75px"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="p-3">
          <h2>{"language item"}</h2>
        </div>
        <div className="card" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
          <div className="card-body">
            <DataTableExtensions exportHeaders columns={columns} data={users}>
              <DataTable
                columns={columns}
                data={users}
                pagination
                defaultSortAsc={false}
                defaultSortField="updated_at"
                noHeader
              />
            </DataTableExtensions>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default UsersAdmin;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not about z-index. Your selection is hiding because the container of your table has overflowY hidden:

```
.hkMDrI {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: inherit;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

So you won't be able to see what is hide outside the height of that `div`.

Width your current `html` I don't think it has any solution unless you don't need scrolling with that table, which I doubt.

Changing the html I would place your `.dropdown-menu`outside the scrolling `div` however you will need `javaScript`to position the element the right place, under the arrow icon.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that such style was applied to datatable. But there is another problem. I want the dropdown menu to go outside table and above of it but it will just add vertical scrolling to table after removing `overflow-y: hidden;`. The only solution was to remove `overflow-x: auto;` as well but i need horizontal scrolling for smaller views. Isn't there any other solution? in your answer you mentioned that i should place `.dropdown-menu` somewhere else and position it using `javascript`. How should i achieve this?

Comment: There's no solution without javasript as I mentioned. I'm afraid I can't help you much there as Im not an javacript expert. You should make another question with a new tag as see if you can get a proper answer. something like how to position a container under a NOT sibling or parent element... just as an idea. gl with your project.

Comment: Ok thanks for your idea. goodluck